# Reactive Subsetting in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I am trying to allow users to choose classes from within a handful of variables, and then the plot I use will dynamically subset from the dataframe only the classes chosen, then plot the output.

So far..

```
ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "NFL"),

dashboardSidebar(
 sidebarMenu(
  selectInput("Year",label = "Year",
   choices = c("2013" = "2013", "2014" = "2014", "2015" = "2015",
                              "2016"= "2016"), selected="2013")
 ),
dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      plotOutput(outputId = "p1"),width = 150
    )
  )
)
server=function(input,output) {
  output$p1 = renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=df, aes_string(x=df$PlayLocation, y=df$YardageResult, 
      color="PlayLocation"))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_jitter()+
    labs (x = ("Play Location"), y = ("Yards Gained"))+
    theme(legend.position="none")
    }
   )
  }
  shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

In this example, I want the x and y variables to remain unchanged, but only show data from the selected year. My final shiny app will have many different variables to further subset, but this is the basic premise.

Any ideas? I have looked into reactive, but am only finding information on how to subset based on indices, and not on matching factor or string values.

Comment: This is covered in the RStudio Shiny tutorial (https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). Take a look at  `reactive`. You need something like this:   `filtered <- reactive( {
    subset(df, year == input$Year)
  })`

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is exactly what I was looking for.